# How can i work with Android EffectFactory Class?

Tags: android, image-processing

I tired to Develop a sample application with image processing, in my app i need to add some `color effects (Grayscale, sepia)` over my bitmap i referred the developer documents [Doc 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html) and [Doc 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html#EFFECT_VIGNETTE), in this document there is no practical examples, so need to know whether we can add Vintage,Sepia color effects using this class, any one guide me  please, Thanks in advance.

Update:

I tried like this,

```
private EffectContext mEffectContext;

Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.sample);
EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
                Effect mEffect = effectFactory
                        .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
```

Now how can i set the mEffect to my bitmap?

Comment: any progress about your problem? I linked to your question in mine

Comment: Have a look at http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
Effect mEffect= effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
```

Then use GLSurfaceView to show the rendered effects, [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/example/android/mediafx/HelloEffects.java) is an example of what you need

Comment: With this we can only show the applied effect on a GL surface view right? How can I retrieve the effect applied bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the official sample project `HelloEffects` in `android-sdk-windows\samples\android-17`