# Using EffectFactory class on bitmap - Android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, effect, bitmapeffect

I want to use `EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH` in my android application. I want to apply this effect on my bitmap but don't know how to do it. I referred both [package-summery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html) and [EffectFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html) links, btu couldn't get much idea. Can anybody guide me to implement this functionality with bitmap. 
Thank you.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832169/how-can-i-work-with-android-effectfactory-class if it helps

Comment: you could have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141823/bitmap-texture-does-not-show-up-in-framebuffer-surface-on-android (its nt really connected to this question, but it could be a guide as to how to use an effect factory in android)

Comment: @Dahra..i already refferd this link and it shows `SEPIA` and `GRAYSCALE` effects but i want to use `LOMOISH` effect as i explained in my question. the 2nd link is for OpenGL, but i want to use it with canvas and views.

Comment: m really new to this :).. how about changing the SEPIA value to LOMOISH.. won't that work ?

Comment: i don't know `Colormatrix` value for `LOMOISH` effect. If you know those values then answer this question.

Comment: i tried searching for the matrix and came across this, dont knw if it will help. [though have a look at it](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/gdk/+/0f8a40e4cfdc5f6cd47c22e81f69ed0446067c54%5E!/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer you want to hear, but (roughly speaking) you can't. The EffectFactory/Effects are not meant to be used with canvas/bitmaps, but are to be applied to OpenGL textures.

Look at the Android [sample](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) (this link doesn't give individual details, but you can create it in Eclipse via new project from sample option) project HelloEffects.

HelloEffects shows how you can use these Effects.