# How use EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE in Android for Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-effects

I would like to apply various filters on a bitmap and I came across:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html

I am not sure how to use it for bitmap (is it possible?).Based on:

[Using EffectFactory class on bitmap - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358911/using-effectfactory-class-on-bitmap-android)

https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/blob/master/HelloEffects/src/com/example/android/mediafx/HelloEffects.java

It's used in conjunction with OpenGL. How do I use it for bitmap filtering?